# $n$ balls that are colorless. You choose $k$ balls, paint $b$ of these balls blue, and paint $r$ of these balls red?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Suppose you have $n$ balls that are colorless. In how many ways can you choose $k$ balls, paint $b$ of these balls blue, and paint $r$ of these balls red?

I have to count this in $2$ ways, right now I have:

$$C(n, k) C(k, r) C(k, b)$$

I am pretty sure that this is the correct answer but I have no clue how else to count this.

Comment: Are you sure about C(N, K) C(K, R) C(K, B)? After you paint B colorless balls blue, are you then going to paint some of those blue balls red? Or are you going to paint only some of the remaining colorless balls red?

Comment: so would it be something like C(N, K) C(K, R) C((K - R), B)

Comment: Yes. Which raises the question: would C(N, K) C(K, R) C((K - R), B) and C(N, K) C(K, B) C((K - B), R) be different ways of counting? That seems too easy.

Comment: No they have to have significant differences.

Comment: There's only way to get the paint job done with colorlessly indistinguisable balls.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the balls distinct?  That is, do they have numbers on them such that it matters *which* balls are chosen, *which* balls are red, and which are blue?  In that case, you need to consider "choice" to account for the different arrangements.  There are  $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose balls to color, then each ball can be colored one of two ways, for $2^k$ combinations.  That is, you’ve already committed to painting the ball in hand, so is it going to be red, or is it going to be blue?  With one ball, two possible outcomes.  With two balls, 4, three gives 8 combinations and so on.  The answer is the product of the choice and the how-to-paint-each-ball.

If not, the problem becomes much simpler.  I envision a hopper of colorless, indistinguishable balls.  The only restriction I see is that k of them must be colored.  Therefore, select k balls out of the hopper--you only do this once--then consider the combinations of painting none of the balls blue (all red), one of the balls blue (k-1 red), two blue (k-2 red) and so on, up to k balls blue.  Since there is no distinguishability among balls, each combination happens once.

Therefore, there are k+1 ways to do this.